# Проблема с удалением cookies в angular 1.3.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookie

Используется  AngularJS v1.3.15
Cookies задаются все нормально, но используется html5mod в route

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

И получается Cookies записалась для /app/ если перешли на другую страницу например /app/1 и тут нам нужно ее удалить то мы удалим ее только со страницы /app/1

Как удалить cookies со всех страниц?

Пытался через $cookieStore

```
 $cookieStore.remove('user_id');
 delete $cookieStore;
 $cookieStore.removeAll();
```

Не один из этих вариантов не работает.

вот тут можно посмотреть как записались cookies.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
$cookies.user_id = '24' - вот так записывались переменные в $cookies

Comment: что за _$cookieStore_? откуда предположение про _Cookies записалась для /app/ если перешли на другую страницу например /app/1 и тут нам нужно ее удалить то мы удалим ее только со страницы /app/1_? Как записываются куки? где они лежат **не самом деле**?

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/3Fy41NJ

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/3Fy41NJ вот тут можно посмотреть как записались cookies.   $cookies.user_id = '24' - вот так записывались переменные в $cookies

Comment: что это за ссылка? если она относится к вопросу - перемести ее в вопрос. Что с ответами на вопросы в комментарии?

Comment: в вопросе у тебя неизвестный `$cookieStore`, в комментарии неизвестные `$cookies`. Определись **что именно** ты используешь, как используешь, и дай ссылку на справку по используемым библиотекам